# PyQt5 - Wait until data is written to QSharedMemory

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pyqt5, ipc

I have 2 separate processes using QSharedMemory for IPC. One of them should have a thread waiting for the other process to write to this shared memory segment and once that happens perform an action (all of this without blocking the main thread).

The file consumer.py:

```py
import time
import threading
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSystemSemaphore, QSharedMemory

sem = QSystemSemaphore("test-sem")
shmem = QSharedMemory("test-shmem")

shmem.create(64, mode=QSharedMemory.ReadWrite)


def wait_for_release():
    while True:
        sem.acquire()
        shmem.lock()
        data = shmem.data()
        data_str = str(data, encoding="utf-8")
        data_str = data_str.rstrip("\x00")
        shmem.unlock()

        print(f"Hello {data_str}!")


threading.Thread(target=wait_for_release).start()

# This should be running while the other thread waits for the semaphore to be released
while True:
    print("Waiting...")
    time.sleep(1)
```

producer.py

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSystemSemaphore, QSharedMemory, QByteArray

sem = QSystemSemaphore("test-sem")
shmem = QSharedMemory("test-shmem")

if shmem.attach(QSharedMemory.ReadWrite):

    str_bytes = QByteArray("World".encode("ascii"))

    shmem.lock()
    shmem.data()[:str_bytes.size()] = str_bytes

    # Release so the other process can print "Hello World!"
    sem.release()
```

The thing I expected to happen when I start running *consumer.py* is the main thread printing "Waiting..." every second and once i run *producer.py* printing "Hello World!" the main thread blocks when the semaphore (which is running in a separate thread) blocks. Does QSystemSemaphore block the whole process? Is there another alternative?

Comment: Are you sure this is related to the additional thread, i.e. have you tried running main consumer code in the main thread?

Comment: Use qt signals to communicate between threads.